# How to Pass Dictionary as Query constraint Parse-Server (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I have a dictionary in the database and I would like my query to have constraints in regards to that dictionary : 
I tried `query.whereEqualTo("skills",dictionary);`
Any idea if this is achievable in parse server and if yes any clarifications?

Comment: If the data is stored as an object at the server, you can use `query.whereEqualTo("skills.dictionary_key",value)` If every key needs to match, maybe iterate over them?

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you !